# Can't get CallbackManager to be fired

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on FB Login integration on my app. I have done all the set-up neccessary and generated my hash-key. I use a custom UI view for the login so I implement the LoginManager in my activty as below

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_front);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // not called
            Log.e("fb_login_sdk", "callback success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // not called
            Log.e("fb_login_sdk", "callback cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            // not called
            Log.e("fb_login_sdk", "callback onError");
        }
    });

    final Activity activity = this;

    face = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.face);
    face.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("fb_login_sdk", "click");
            List<String> perm = new ArrayList<String>();
            perm.add("email");
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(activity, perm);
        }
    });
```

With this, the highest I have gotten is the onclick on the imageview log. I have implemented this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("Results", String.valueOf(resultCode));
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

but none of the logs are printed apart from the one at the beginning of the click event. When I press the button, a spinner shows briefly and then the app just end (not crash). How do I get this to work, its driving me crazy as I have spent about a day tring to get this to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it was a simple and perhaps an oversight. As @Arkar pointed out, I forgot to remove this from my AndroidManifest file for that particular Activity and hence there was not callback triggered.

```
android:noHistory
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use application context instead of activity context when you initialize facebook sdk.

Replace this

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
```

with

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please check this one !! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233177/login-callback-is-not-triggered-using-facebook-android-sdk-4